# Problems with Jasypt, package-info.java

Tags: java, jpa, jetty, guice, jasypt

I am using JPA with Guice, Jasypt and GWT+Jetty server,

I am trying to create a custom types for the encrypted columns.

I have create the package-info.java where I have the custom types. The package-info.java is located in the package with the persistence classes.

In the persistence classes I have annotated the columns for the specific encryption.

When I start the jetty in devmode I get the following error:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory     at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)

......

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: encryptedDateAsString, at table: employee, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(encrypted_birth_date)]

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you are lacking a `@TypeDef` declaration in your entity for the `encryptedDateAsString` type you are using?

For example:

```
@Entity
@TypeDef {
  name = "encryptedDateAsString",
  typeClass = org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedDateAsStringType.class
}
```

Disclaimer for editors: I'm the author of jasypt.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for your answer.I've made a simple test project (console application) and the TypeDef is located in the package-info.java and it's working but in the Guice+JPA project is not working. The solution that i've made for the Guice+JPA is to have a abstract class with the TypeDef declaration and the persistence classes will extend that class. Is this a suitable solution ? Thanks